# Debug a custom solution for Sharepoint 2010 in visual studio

Tags: sharepoint, sandbox, solution

I built the WSP file manually (using CAB utility) and uploaded them to the sharepoint 2010 server. I want to debug the dll that was packaged in that WSP file to test if the events are caught by the listener. I attached to w3wp.exe (all instances that appears). however I find that the symbols are not loaded for any break point to be hit and the thread is getting exited with some run time exception.

what Am I missing here ?  Do I have to copy my PDB files at any particular location ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have the answer in your question. yes you have to upload your pdb file to GAC using command prompt and copy statement 
 which would be available under 
C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL> in directory form open it and copy your pdb thier

or easier option is compile your wsp in debug format

Answer (score 0):

You [don't need to copy the PDB symbols file into the GAC](http://www.elumenotion.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=23) if Visual Studio is configured correctly :-

> Fortunately, it's just as easy to
>   debug in the GAC as it is in BIN if
>   you configure the development
>   environment correctly.
>
> Unfortunately,
>   few know how to do this because the
>   internet is polluted with pages full
>   of bad information that is a held over
>   from previous versions of .Net.
>
> You
>   can spot these easily because they
>   will say you need to copy the debug
>   symbols (.pdb file) to the GAC. In and
>   of itself, that will not work. These
>   days it is also completely
>   unnecessary.
>
> [To configure VS ... to debug the
>   assemblies properly](http://www.elumenotion.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=23), do the following:

Comment: this is not very effective approach as The "Just My Code" option claims to optimize assembly loading.

Answer (score 0):

You mention the Sandbox tag in your question, so you have to attach to SPUCWorkerProcess.exe and not w3wp.exe, the sandbox code runs in an isolated worker.